# Flutter Firebase Messaging Crashing Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE

Tags: android, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

Recently we released android application targets to 31 which has reported more crashes (only Android OS 12 users) in Firebase Messaging (PendingIntent). When Application is in Pause/Background state on Notification Receive its crashing.
I've tried possible solutions but no luck still crashing. As i understood is we have to add PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE on PendingIntent start activity but not getting any idea how to add or fix this.

If anyone faced same issue and fixed. Share solution for this.

Thanks in advance...

```
dependencies{
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.0'
}
```

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 7058): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.package: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
E/AndroidRuntime( 7058): Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
E/AndroidRuntime( 7058):    at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7058):    at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivityAsUser(PendingIntent.java:458)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7058):    at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:444)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7058):    at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:408)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7058):    at com.google.firebase.messaging.CommonNotificationBuilder.createContentIntent(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.3.0:125)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7058):    at com.google.firebase.messaging.CommonNotificationBuilder.createNotificationInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.3.0:27)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7058):    at com.google.firebase.messaging.CommonNotificationBuilder.createNotificationInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.3.0:9)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7058):    at com.google.firebase.messaging.DisplayNotification.handleNotification(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.3.0:27)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7058):    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.dispatchMessage(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.3.0:65)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7058):    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.passMessageIntentToSdk(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.3.0:44)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7058):    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.handleMessageIntent(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.3.0:27)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7058):    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.handleIntent(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.3.0:17)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7058):    at com.google.firebase.messaging.EnhancedIntentService.lambda$processIntent$0$EnhancedIntentService(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.3.0:43)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7058):    at com.google.firebase.messaging.EnhancedIntentService$$Lambda$0.run(Unknown Source:6)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7058):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7058):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7058):    at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.6.0:2)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7058):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
W/CrashlyticsCore( 7058): Cannot send reports. Settings are unavailable.
D/TransportRuntime.SQLiteEventStore( 7058): Storing event with priority=HIGHEST, name=FIREBASE_CRASHLYTICS_REPORT for destination cct
```

Comment: paste your show notification code

Comment: @Avital sorry not getting. Show Notification Code mean? Am using Flutter Local Notification when notification receiving onMessage. do you asking that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I resolved this finally. Its crashed due to lower version of Firebase Plugins and after upgrading the Android Dependencies and Flutter plugins it got resolved.

Step 1: In android/app/build.gradle

**From**

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.5'
```

**To**

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom') // add this 
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0' // add this
```

Step 2: In Flutter pubspec.yaml

**From**

```
firebase_core: ^0.5.0+1
firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3
firebase_remote_config: ^0.4.2
firebase_crashlytics: ^0.1.4+1
firebase_dynamic_links: ^0.6.3
firebase_auth: ^0.18.4+1
```

**To**

```
firebase_core: ^1.10.0
firebase_messaging: ^11.2.6
firebase_remote_config: ^2.0.0
firebase_crashlytics: ^2.5.0
firebase_dynamic_links: ^4.0.5
firebase_auth: ^3.3.6
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am also faced this issue this answer helps me to fix...

Comment: I'm using an old version of flutter and dart 2.12 didn't upgraded my app yet, so is there another way to fix this issue ? thx

Answer (score 3):

As per the official doc "**If your app targets Android 12, you must specify the mutability of each PendingIntent object that your app creates. This additional requirement improves your app's security.**"

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

   
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,NOTIFICATION_REQUEST_CODE, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
```

we’re constructing a standard type of Intent that will open our app, and then simply wrapping that in a PendingIntent before adding it to our notification.In this case, since we have an exact action we know we want to perform, we construct a PendingIntent that cannot be modified by the app we pass it to by utilizing a flag called **FLAG_IMMUTABLE.**

Comment: thanks for replying. Yes you are correct as per the official doc if application using target level 31 we have to add FLAG_IMMUTABLE. But my question is am using Flutter Firebase Messaging Plugin and from firebase-messaging onMessage receive app is getting crashed like above mentioned. How to add that FLAG_IMMUTABLE and solve in `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging`?

Comment: share your code of firebase-messaging onMessage method.

Answer (score 0):

update `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:`

From

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.5'
```

To

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.0'  
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0'
```

and sync project with Gradle Files